# arm; OR switch; asm;

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, arm, arm64

I'm thinking about an efficient way to implement the following code on ARM asm.

I have 4x8bit values packed in one 32bit word so that [x:y:z:w]. Every one of them in range [0-7].

The condition is 
`if( (x==0) || (y==0) || (z==0) || (w==0) ) goto _jump0; // skip part of initialization`

Currently I use straight forward solution like

```
    tst         val         , #(255)
    beq         .L.jump0
    tst         val         , #(255<<16)
    beq         .L.jump0
    tst         val         , #(255<<32)                                   
    beq         .L.jump0
    tst         val         , #(255<<48)
    beq         .L.jump0
```

Is there a way to do it more effectively?
Thanks.

Comment: [Determine if a word has a zero byte](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord)

Comment: Interesting solution. But it would also require 2 constants reading from the memory (0x01010101UL; 0x80808080UL). Memory access is quite heavy instructions and they would eliminate benefits.

Comment: those constants can be encoded in a single instruction since `mov` allows immediates of form [`0xXYXYXYXY`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/Chdfgchf.html), no memory access is needed

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, you are right! Thanks.

Comment: Since you're on ARM64, why not use NEON to do 16 at a time? Use something like vceq.8 against a register full of zeros, then pairwise add the result and compare against zero. The result will be less than 1 clock cycle per byte.

Comment: @BitBank, majority of NEON instructions take 3 cycle. Moving from GPR to NEON and vise versa takes 5 ticks. So totally, `mov d0[0], w0, cmeq ..., addp ..., addp ..., mov w0, d0[0], tst w0, b.eq ...` 7 instructions (2 are heavy `MOV`s). It's definitely is not faster option. But thanks for your option.

Comment: @user3124812 - I'm not sure where you get your information, but you have it quite wrong about NEON instructions. The majority of NEON instructions take 1 clock cycle. Also, you can load directly into a NEON register instead of mov d0[0],w0. It is definitely much faster to use NEON for your purposes if you have more than a total of 4 bytes to compare.

Comment: @BitBank depends on the nature of the algorithm - if you can't spare the registers and/or unroll enough iterations to fit the pipeline, and the next instruction needs the result of the current one as input, then the 2 cycles this instruction takes to _complete_ over and above the 1 it takes to _issue_ are going to start to matter.

Comment: @Notlikethat - obviously it's a pipelined architecture and proper interleaving of instructions needs to be taken into consideration. The OP cares about performance and would hopefully understand how the target machine works before writing code full of pipeline stalls.

Comment: @BitBank, timings are described in this document [Cortex-A57 Software Optimisation Guide](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_n6_vlYHKAhViJaYKHdIKBswQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Finfocenter.arm.com%2Fhelp%2Ftopic%2Fcom.arm.doc.uan0015a%2Fcortex_a57_software_optimisation_guide_external.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFWHlGyc4flEROlmEVgsE5_EYzvSg&sig2=UIycWVU3mctpMBXUplB97w&bvm=bv.110151844,d.dGY)

Comment: @user3124812 - Yes they are described in that link and if you actually read it, you'll see that the majority of NEON instructions (non-floating point) take a single clock cycle. The 3-5 cycle number is for the total number of clocks to complete (that's what happens in a pipelined architecture). If you properly interleave your instructions, you can achieve the 1 (or less) clocks per instruction. If you don't understand pipelining, I can't teach you in a comment, but here's a link that describes it pretty well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)

Comment: Maybe we're talking past each other about 2 different issues. You haven't described the rest of the software around this one small area. If it's just a single 4-byte value that's being compared, then NEON doesn't make sense and the original code you have is fine. If you are working with lots of these groups, then a SIMD solution will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a register to spare, you can preload a constant mask value:

```
   mov w1,#0x01010101    @ mov allows loading a repeated byte
```

Then your problem fits in 5 instructions (slower in some cases, faster in others)

```
   orr w0,w0,w0,LSR #1   @ since values are 0-7, combine the 3 bits
   orr w0,w0,w0,LSR #2
   and w0,w0,w1          @ mask off the bits we care about
   cmp w0,w1             @ any zeros present?
   bne there_is_a_zero
```